# Topic modelling with Python subprocess.CalledProcessError

Tags: python, gensim, topic-modeling

I need to create a topic modelling for my uni project, and what I'm doing is trying to repeat what this guy is doing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TgXLq1XIdA0

So far I'm running his code till the line 45, I'm copying it here:

```
#creating our first topic model :)
#importing the necessary libraries
import gensim, nltk, os

#defining lists to work on with
#tokens from each file stored here
texts = []
#files' names
labels = []

#iterating through all files in the corpus folder
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('CEOs_speeches_all'):
    for file_name in files:
        with open(os.path.join(root, file_name),encoding='utf8') as rf:
            #opening each file as a text for reading
            text = rf.read()
            #tokenising words with nltk
            tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
            #getting rid of all tokens that are not numerical or alphabetical i.e. spaces, punctuation
            cleaned = [word for word in tokens if word.isalnum()]
            texts.append(cleaned)
            #putting files' names without extension (.txt) into the list
            labels.append(file_name[:-4])

#transforming the corpus to run in gensim
corpus_dictionary = gensim.corpora.Dictionary(texts)
corpus_dictionary.filter_extremes(no_below=5)
#transforming the corpus text list into the list of bags of words
processed_corpus = [corpus_dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]

#printing the first file for checking
#print(processed_corpus[0])

#defining the number of topics
number_of_topics = 10

#specifying where mallet lives
mallet_path = os.path.join("C:\mallet", "bin", "mallet")

#creating the mallet modeling object
lda_model = gensim.models.wrappers.ldamallet.LdaMallet(
    mallet_path,
    corpus=processed_corpus,
    id2word=corpus_dictionary,
    num_topics=number_of_topics,
    optimize_interval=10,
    prefix='fed_'
)
```

and I get this error message:
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'C:\mallet/bin/mallet import-file --preserve-case --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords --token-regex "\S+" --input fed_corpus.txt --output fed_corpus.mallet' returned non-zero exit status 127.

Could someone help to fix, please? Any ideas?

UPDATE: I changed the line mallet_path = os.path.join("C:\mallet", "bin", "mallet") to mallet_path = "~/mallet/bin/mallet" but it still shows the same error :/

Answer (score 0):

You seem to work in a Linux environment but the path in the example is written for Windows. You need to update the variable `mallet_path` with the right path on your computer.